# How to make custom windows interface completely different than standard window style like of Cyberlink PowerDVD

Tags: windows, winapi, custom-controls

I can make default styled windows using win32 API for my windows application. Now I need to draw custom windows with custom border, custom maximize, minimize buttons, custom styled windows controls similer to PowerDVD or JetAudio Media Player.

I cannot find any related article on MSDN and from google, Can anybody help me? Any related URL or code snippets with visual C++ or Win32 API will be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winapi : Handling custom and default non-client controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490627/winapi-handling-custom-and-default-non-client-controls)

Comment: @Raymond Chen: this is not duplicate, he's talking about Custom Styles, not custom Controls as you've suggested